# MaterializeCSS - Icons and fonts not aligning

Tags: css, materialize

I moved from BS4 to Material, and have been making use of Material Icons but I'm having a consistent issue with alignment.
[image: Template Image]
[image: BreadCrumb]

Sometimes it's an obvious change - Such as the breadcrumb, and sometimes it's small as in the case of the button.

I have VERY little CSS that is non-Material, and none of it should be modifying the font.

The CSS I apply to the Breadcrumb to make it align is along the effects of:

```
.breadcrumb-nav
  height: 35px
  line-height: 35px
  padding-left: 150px

.breadcrumb_current
  border-bottom: 3px solid $divider-color
```

Which works beautifully, but I have to apply CSS to every Material Icon, or element that has a graphic, currently. Is this a known issue, or am I missing something?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/awjxfwne/2/

My breadcrumb issue was poor comprehension:

```
<div class="breadcrumb-nav">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="col s12">
            <a class="breadcrumb">
                <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
            </a>
            <a class="breadcrumb ">
                <a class="breadcrumb_current">Statements Overview</a>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Should have been

```
<div class="breadcrumb-nav">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="col s12">
                <%= link_to 'Home', root_path, :class => "breadcrumb" %>
                <a class="breadcrumb">Statements Overview</a>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Comment: @ChandraShekhar Attached.

Comment: use vertical-align:middle for material-icons

Comment: @jaseelmp On what element, though? The `<i>`, the containing `<div>` the text `<span>`

Comment: for <i> tag element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The markup for the icon should be as follows:

```
<i class="material-icons left">add</i>
```

Without the `left` class, your icon will look off.

Comment: Sure enough that's the issue in the button. What about the breadcrum scenario? Should you also append 'left' on those?

Comment: I don't think so. The documentation doesn't place the icons in the markup and rather is displayed via CSS `content` property. See if your markup is correct: http://materializecss.com/breadcrumbs.html

Comment: @DNorthrup update the post with the markup for breadcrumb. You might be interfering with the Materialize CSS somewhere.

Comment: Yea.... sure enough. I had the <a> with the breadcrumb class AROUND the actual link. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS

CSS

```
.s12 .btn .material-icons{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change the icon margin-top to negative value or any value to align it.
For example,

```
<i class="material-icons" style="margin-top:-10px">android</i>
```